# Do these two have's the same meaning?

Tags: vocabulary

> At first, Gryffindors passing the giant hourglasses that recorded the
>   house points the next day thought there'd been a mistake. How could
>   they suddenly **have a hundred and fifty points fewer** than
>   yesterday? And then the story started to spread: Harry Potter, the
>   famous Harry Potter, their hero of two Quidditch matches, had lost
>   them all those points, him and a couple of other stupid first years. 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The bold structure has an adjective (fewer) instead of past participle. But it seems highly resembling this: 22.(used *with a past participle*) have something done to suffer the effects of what somebody else does to you. She had her bag stolen. ([Oxford Advanced](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/have)). Are the two the same cases or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same, because "a hundred and fifty points fewer than yesterday" is not a past participle.

Your example could also have been worded

> How could they suddenly have a hundred and fifty fewer points than yesterday?

The question is is asking, how could the team have lost 150 points.

This is essentially the first sense of *have* from the dictionary you linked, "to own, hold or possess something"; in this case the thing is points.

A similar example, as far as the use of *to have* goes, would be,

> At the end of the game, the Bears had 49 points and the Giants had 17.